# Retrieve the path of Image from gallery into Edittext

Tags: android, android-intent, gallery

I want to Achieve the following in my project:

1. open the `Gallery`  on clicking an Edittext.
2. select an `Image` or `File` in the gallery and get its path into my edittext.

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: @Nikka - not sure why your edit was approved, especially since, while attempting to clean up grammar, you actually introduced an error.

Answer (score 0):

On your `onActivityResult`
`Uri uri = intent.getData();`
And then grap that uri path this way
`MyEditText.setText(uri.getPath());`

Answer (score 0):

try this,

For open gallary,

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
                            intent.setType("image/*");
                            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, ""), PICK_IMAGE);
```

use this method to get image path,

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, final Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            switch (requestCode) {

                case PICK_IMAGE:

            String imagepath =  (getAbsolutePath(data.getData()) + "|").split("\\|");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }


public String getAbsolutePath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaColumns.DATA };
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaColumns.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        } else
            return null;
    }
```